# Which resources are needed to use Blue Prism with Azure Computer Vision?

Tags: azure, computer-vision, azure-web-app-service, blueprism

Hello we are implementing a bot developed in Blue Prism which will read pdf documents, extract the information within them (name of the creator, category, date) and then classify it on the corresponding folder.
We want to implement Computer Vision on Azure in order to achieve this, my question is which Azure resources are needed to achieve this? We want to get a price estimate in order to determine if we move forward with the project. I've used the calculator, but it gives us a cost of around 20 USD to use CV, but sometimes other resources are needed to connect with it. Which resources would these be? What does Blue Prism need?

Comment: "*but sometimes other resources are needed to connect with it*" Which resources are you referring to? Can you provide a source for this claim? In my experience, if you have a Computer Vision resource spun up, simply providing the region and API key to the Azure Computer Vision VBO is plenty sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

I think Form Recognizer is more fit for this scenario, which has better layout, structure:
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/cognitive-services/form-recognizer/

For Computer Vision, I will recommend Read API for your scenario:
https://westcentralus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/computer-vision-v3-1-ga/operations/5d986960601faab4bf452005

Thanks.